# What is the probability of items spawned in chests?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I found items in a chest in the Nether and found a golden chestplate and saddle, but nothing great like diamonds or emeralds.  So, I wanted to know the probability of good items spawning in chests.

[image: A chest in the Neather]

I wouldn't mind knowing the likelihood of spawned items off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 1.9, generated chests rely on [loot tables](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Loot_table) to populate loot. This makes it much easier to determine probability as the loot tables can be extracted from the jar and evaluated directly.

For nether fortresses, which use the `chests/nether_bridge.json` table (2-4 rolls):

```
ID                     Amount     Chance
```

```
diamond                1-3        6.849%
iron_ingot             1-5        6.849%
gold_ingot             1-3        20.548%
golden_sword           1          6.849%
golden_chestplate      1          6.849%
flint_and_steel        1          6.849%
nether_wart            3-7        6.849%
saddle                 1          13.699%
golden_horse_armor     1          10.959%
iron_horse_armor       1          6.849%
diamond_horse_armor    1          4.110%
obsidian               2-4        2.740%
```

Note that each percentage is per-roll, and there are 2-4 rolls for this table. Each roll is brand new and will not be affected by previous results (such that it will always be a 6.849% chance *per roll* for diamond).

Comment: Are they different for abandoned Mine Shafts/Dungeons/Strongholds?

Comment: @Jason_ Yes, each and every loot table has its own contents that you can look through.

Answer (score 0):

The cance of a good loot is random I sometimes get dimonds and sometimes I get complete junk. So you need to keep going to nether fortresses and hope luck is on your side basically.

Comment: Programming can't really be very random so there should be some probability.

Comment: @Jason_  unless the game is SUPPOSED to run on random